# How can I make Tomcat 6 show the real error instead of a 404?

Tags: tomcat6, http-status-code-404

For deploying and troubleshooting an application, getting 404s has little use.  I have deployed applications that report no issue in the logs but return 404s.  There IS an error in the application as I've found it through some trial and error.

Is there a way to have Tomcat actually return the error it's encountering as opposed to the 404?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: They don't say anything.  The server loaded up.  The web app is present.  I looked in the admin console, the web app is there.

Comment: The logs should always say something. I suspect you're not looking in the right place. If there really are no logs, then you must have them disabled.

Comment: The WAR being deployed was an incomplete archive.  It was missing some files that caused the web app to not function.  The logs didn't indicate anything was amiss (and maybe they wouldn't have in this case).  Back to my original question...

Answer (score 1):

If there is no servlet taking up this path, there is pretty little Tomcat can do to even know the "real" error.

If there is definitely a servlet assigned to the path that gives the 404 error, you should check this servlet.
The JSF Facelets Servlet for example notoriously (and annoyingly) throws a 404 by default, if a page exists, but is missing an included file.